Como puedo acceder al numero de referencia de memoria ram de una variable u objeto en JS
Quiero saber como ver el numero de referencia donde se guardan las variables, objetos, array o cualquier tipo en la memoria ram, con que codigo

¿Es por simple curiosidad o tiene alguna aplicación útil?

obtener la dirección como tal no es posible, no hay implementación que lo haga

Las referencias a memoria en JS son manejadas por el motor de JS y no son accesibles desde el código de JS. Puedes ver esta pregunta del sitio en inglés cuyas respuestas explican el porqué.

No tiene mucho sentido ver esa clase de cosas en un lenguaje de alto nivel. Si buscas obtener una especie de id, aquí hay algo interesante https://stackoverflow.com/q/1997661/

Diferente de algunos lenguajes que permiten mostrar la dirección de memoria de variables y objetos, esto es difícil en JavaScript, ya que el lenguaje hace una abstracción de la memoria de las variables y objetos.
Acceder directamente a la dirección de memoria no es posible, pero manipular referencias de objetos y obtener información son formas accesibles. La asignación, comparación y paso de referencia son las formas directas de trabajar con objetos.
En ciertos casos, el WeakRef puede ser útil. El objeto WeakRef contiene una referencia mínima de un objeto que permitirá que el Garbage Collection recupere la memoria del objeto si no hay otras referencias más detalladas.
Sin embargo, al usar WeakRef no se proporcionará acceso directo a la dirección de memoria del objeto. Incluso algunas referencias en línea mencionan este hecho. Solo mantendrá una referencia, pero no impedirá el Garbage Collection.
Lo que sucederá es que el Garbage Collection liberará la memoria del objeto antes de que se acceda a la referencia y devolverá una variable inválida.
¿Qué es esta abstracción de memoria? Es la memoria siendo gestionada automáticamente por el garbage collector, a diferencia de lenguajes como C o C++.
Lo que hace WeakRef es mantener una referencia baja, pero no impedirá que el objeto sea recolectado por el garbage collector y no mostrará la dirección de memoria, solo accederá al objeto mientras no haya sido recolectado y mostrará la referencia.
